# Distribute columns evenly

Tags: multicolumn

I am writing an article and when I create the next table I have a problem

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{multirow} % para las tablas
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}% paquete para manejo de números y unidades
\sisetup{detect-weight, detect-display-math}
\sisetup{detect-inline-weight=math}
\sisetup{mode=text,per-mode=symbol}% modo de unidades con barra en lugar de fracción de tamaño reducido
\usepackage{multirow}% para tablas
\usepackage{makecell}% para tablas
\usepackage{booktabs}% para tablas
\usepackage{graphicx}% para gráficos
\usepackage{pgfplots}% para gráficos
\usepackage{pdflscape}% para gráficos
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}% para gráficos
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}% para gráficos
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}% para gráficos
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}% para gráficos
\newlength\fwidth% definido en el código de Matlab
\setlength{\fwidth}{0.8\textwidth}% defino valor de parámetro fwidth de gráficos
\usepackage{tikzscale}% para gráficos
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}% para gráficos
\usepackage{overpic}% figuras
\usepackage{tikz}% figuras
\usepackage{pgfplots}% figuras
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}% setea márgenes de hoja
\usepackage{bicaption}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Chemical properties of OS on dry basis}
\label{Chemical properties of OS on dry basis}
\resizebox{15cm}{1.2cm}{
\begin{tabular}{
        S[table-format=2.0]
        *{9}S[table-format=2.0]
    }
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Proximate analysis(wt.\%)}}  & 
    \multicolumn{7}{c}{\thead{Ultimate analysis}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-9}
    {\thead{Sample}} & {\thead{C}}    & {\thead{H}}    & 
    {\thead{O$^a$}}    & {\thead{N}}    & {\thead{S}}    & {\thead{VM}}     & {\thead{FC$^b$}}     & {\thead{Ash}} & {\thead{HHV(MJ/kg)}} \\
    \midrule
     OS & 9.3 & 2.3 & 11.6 & 0.2 & 4.0 & 24.0 & 3.4 & 72.6 & 2.9 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}}\\\smallskip
\parbox{1\textwidth}{
    \scriptsize OS: oil shale; C: carbon; H: hidrogen; O: oxigen; N: nitrogen; S: sulfur; VM: volatile matter; FC: fixed carbon; HHV: high heating value.\\a-By difference: O\%= 100\%-C\%-H\%-N\%-S\%-Ash\%\\b-By difference: FC= 100\%-VM\%-Ash\%}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

My problem is that the columns are not evenly distribute, could anybody help me?

Cheers!

Comment: Hi, can you turn your snippet into a complete example? I.e. add a documentclass, the packages that are required to run the code, and a `document` environment.

Comment: Ready, i added the environment

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: Nearly all the packages you load are loaded more than once, which only contributes to cluttering your preamble. Might be a good idea to check whether you already load a package, before adding it in.

Comment: and also check if all loaded package is necessary to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: I deleted some usepackages, however my problem continues

Comment: I did specifically say in my previous comment "*unrelated to your problem*" ... An addition to Steven's answer: It doesn't make sense that your first column is an `S` column (which is for aligning numbers), when it only contains text, I'd replace it with `l`. For the last nine columns, you have one decimal point, so why not use `table-format=2.1`? And finally, all the `\resizebox` does at the moment is to needlessly distort your table. I'd definitely remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you want your `\multicolumn`s to be `5` and `3` columns wide, rather than `2` and `7`?

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{multirow} % para las tablas
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}% paquete para manejo de números y unidades
\sisetup{detect-weight, detect-display-math}
\sisetup{detect-inline-weight=math}
\sisetup{mode=text,per-mode=symbol}% modo de unidades con barra en lugar de fracción de tamaño reducido
\usepackage{multirow}% para tablas
\usepackage{makecell}% para tablas
\usepackage{booktabs}% para tablas
\usepackage{graphicx}% para gráficos
\usepackage{pgfplots}% para gráficos
\usepackage{pdflscape}% para gráficos
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}% para gráficos
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}% para gráficos
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}% para gráficos
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}% para gráficos
\newlength\fwidth% definido en el código de Matlab
\setlength{\fwidth}{0.8\textwidth}% defino valor de parámetro fwidth de gráficos
\usepackage{tikzscale}% para gráficos
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}% para gráficos
\usepackage{overpic}% figuras
\usepackage{tikz}% figuras
\usepackage{pgfplots}% figuras
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}% setea márgenes de hoja
\usepackage{bicaption}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Chemical properties of OS on dry basis}
\label{Chemical properties of OS on dry basis}
\resizebox{15cm}{1.2cm}{
\begin{tabular}{
        S[table-format=2.0]
        *{9}S[table-format=2.0]
    }
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\thead{Proximate analysis(wt.\%)}}  & 
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{Ultimate analysis}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-9}
    {\thead{Sample}} & {\thead{C}}    & {\thead{H}}    & 
    {\thead{O$^a$}}    & {\thead{N}}    & {\thead{S}}    & {\thead{VM}}     & {\thead{FC$^b$}}     & {\thead{Ash}} & {\thead{HHV(MJ/kg)}} \\
    \midrule
     OS & 9.3 & 2.3 & 11.6 & 0.2 & 4.0 & 24.0 & 3.4 & 72.6 & 2.9 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}}\\\smallskip
\parbox{1\textwidth}{
    \scriptsize OS: oil shale; C: carbon; H: hidrogen; O: oxigen; N: nitrogen; S: sulfur; VM: volatile matter; FC: fixed carbon; HHV: high heating value.\\a-By difference: O\%= 100\%-C\%-H\%-N\%-S\%-Ash\%\\b-By difference: FC= 100\%-VM\%-Ash\%}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]